# Import script or use CDN

Tags: javascript

I'm using [fetch-jsonp](https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp) in my react app running ES6, and im unable to import the script with `import fecthjsonp from 'fetch-jsonp';`- if anyone knows what the problem is please care to explain.
The script seems to be imported but the console returns `fetchjsonp undefined`

However, this got me wondering - What is the best way to include a script like this? Using import or just drop a script tab in my HTML with the CDN?

Comment: If you can - use CDN. If you are using a well-used script it's probably already exists in the user's brower's cache, and if not - the big CDNs probably have better servers/bandwidth/connectivity/replications over the world.

Comment: Another way, apart of using CDN, could be to bundle it with other packages in your application.

Comment: Your imported name has a typo (`fecthjsonp` !== `fetchjsonp`)

Comment: Jesus christ... Thanks :)